# Find $\oint_{|z|=1} \cos\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)\cos(z)\, dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I have taken the power series of $\cos\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$ as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{(\frac{1}{z})^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ and $\cos(z)$ as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}$ and multiply those together. How do I proceed? Do I use the residue theorem or some other method?

Comment: Hint: Rewrite $\cos(z)$ as $\frac12(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})$.

Comment: Note that there are no odd powers of $z$ or $1/z$ implicated in the series for $\cos(z)$ and $\cos(1/z)$.  Can there possibly be any odd powers implicated in their product?  Answer that question and then answer what the coefficient is on the $1/z$ term in the Laurent expansion of the product.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track.  Note that there are no odd powers of $z$ or $1/z$ implicated in the series for $\cos(z)$ and the series for $\cos(1/z)$.

Hence the Cauchy product for $\cos(z)\cos(1/z)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k \left(\sum_{\ell=0}^k \frac{1}{(2k)!(2(k-\ell))!}\right)\,z^{2(2\ell-k)}$ has no odd powers of $z$.

We conclude, therefore, that coefficient on $1/z$ of the Laurent series for $\cos(z)\cos(1/z)$ is zero, which implies the residue at $z=0$ of $\cos(z)\cos(1/z)$ is also zero.